# Set Current TimeZone to @JsonFormat timezone value

Tags: java, json, timezone, spring-data-jpa, dto

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy", timezone = "Asia/Kolkata")
private Date activationDate;
```

From the above java code, I want to set timezone value as Current System timezone using below:
**TimeZone.getDefault().getID()** - it returns value as **"Asia/Kolkata"**

But if i set this code to json format

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy", timezone = TimeZone.getDefault().getID())
```

I am getting error like **"The value for annotation attribute JsonFormat.timezone must be a constant expression"**

Pls help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance,
Vishnu

Comment: I think you must define a deserializer for this task, but haven't tried yet. I am in such situation, too. If you have something, please attach your solution below, thanks.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? If yes then please update

Answer (score 16):

You can use `JsonFormat.DEFAULT_TIMEZONE`, **after properly configuring the ObjectMapper**:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy", timezone = JsonFormat.DEFAULT_TIMEZONE)
```

From the docs:

> Value that indicates that default TimeZone (from deserialization or serialization context) should be used: annotation does not define value to use.
>
> **NOTE: default here does NOT mean JVM defaults but Jackson databindings default, usually UTC, but may be changed on ObjectMapper.**

In order to configure the `ObjectMapper`:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyApp {

    @Autowired
    public void configureJackson(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        objectMapper.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    }
}
```

To set the default TimeZone on your application use this JVM property:

```
-Duser.timezone=Asia/Kolkata
```

Comment: Not entirely correct. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55225726/10513675

Comment: Looks like javadoc a little bit misleading https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1266

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for pointing out the inaccuracies, I updated the answer. Jackson updated their Javadocs too.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot assign **timezone** value a dynamic or a runtime value. It should be constant or a compile time value and **enums** too accepted.

So you should assign a constant to **timezone**. like below.

```
private static final String MY_TIME_ZONE="Asia/Kolkata";
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy", timezone = MY_TIME_ZONE);
```

Comment: Hi Raju Sharma,
i want to set time zone as system's current time zone, dont need to assign constant value like "Asia/Kolkata".

Thanks

Comment: I dont understand why default it UTC and not the current system timestamp? Also why cant serialize to the value it holds? This is strange

Answer (score -1):

You can use enumeration in order to possibly enrich you time zones that you would use. A solution using enumeration is the following enumeration class implementation.

```
    package <your package goes here>;

    import java.util.TimeZone;


    public enum TimeZoneEnum {

        DEFAULT(TimeZone.getDefault()),
        ASIA_KOLKATA = (TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Abidjan")),
        //other timezones you maybe need
        ...


    private final TimeZone tz;

        private TimeZoneEnum(final TimeZone tz)
        {
            this.tz = tz;
        }

        public final TimeZone getTimeZone()
        {
            return tz;
        }
    }
```

Then you can utilize you enumeration like below:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy", timezone = TimeZoneEnum.ASIA_KOLKATA )
```

Comment: Thanks Dude,

Using above code, still im getting same error "The value for annotation attribute JsonFormat.timezone must be a constant expression"